# Search list of dictionaries for name python

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, dataset

I have a list of dictionaries that each have data like this:

```
'Caitlyn': {'date': (2012, 11, 24), 'player': 'Caitlyn', 'outcome': 'Win', 'gameid': '00006', 'stats': {'assists': 6, 'kills': 13, 'deaths': 4}}
```

which I generate each item from a file with lines and data like this:

```
[00006] Caitlyn - 13/4/6 - Win - 2012-11-24
```

I want to get all indexes of a matching player name in the list of dictionaries and print them and/or print the data in them. I can print all of the list and format it to match my file etc, but I'm not sure how to go about searching it since it's a bit different then the other searches i'm doing in this.

I am able to print the entire data set with this (ugly I know, but it works):

```
i = 0
for item in records:
    print "\n", "[%s] %s - %s/%s/%s - %s - %s-%s-%s" % (records[i][0], records[i][1]['player'], records[i][1]['stats']['kills'], records[i][1]['stats']['deaths'], records[i][1]['stats']['assists'], records[i][1]['outcome'], records[i][1]['date'][0], records[i][1]['date'][1], records[i][1]['date'][2])
    i = i + 1
```

Can anyone help with this a bit? I need to be able to search it for player name and print out each match of that (and return the index so I can work with the matched set for other stuff instead of running the whole search again), and i think i want to return a list of the matches so i can resort them or export them or whatever. Thanks for any assistance!

**[edit] Since there seem to be more questions then answers so far, here is the entire file so far:**
http://www.pasteall.org/37589/python

and this is the stats4.txt:
http://www.pasteall.org/37590

Comment: Just as a start, you can use enumerate and save yourself the trouble of keeping track of an incrementing counter, i.e. `for i, item in enumerate(records):`

Comment: A list of dictionaries, or a dictionary containing dictionaries? Lists can't have named entries (`'Caitlyn': {`...)

Comment: Even better, just drop the loop counter. Inside the loop, `item is records[i]`. Also, what does the `player` field do? You have duplicate information there.

Comment: the dictionary example i posted is one item in the list, there are others for each line of the input statistics file, the player field is there because I couldn't come up with another way to get that out while not having to reference the player name directly to get data out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pleasure to meet another summoner at an unexpected place like this.

If you want to track all games played with a specific champion, you can build another dictionary with champion name as the key and list of game stats as the value.

The code should look like this.

```
records = {}

for line in data:
    # parsing codes

    # store player -> gameid mappings to the index
    if player not in records:
        records[player] = []
    records[player].append(info)

print records['Sona']
# this should print out list of games played with Sona
```

This change will make your data accessible by champion name, but is no longer sorted by game ID. If you still need to access your data by game ID, I suggest you to store data by game ID, and build another dictionary to index that. It depends on what you want to do with the data.

Also, if you want to do some serious analysis with this data, you should consider using some database bindings for python, like [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), which is included in the standard library. Database is application designed exactly for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thank you ill see if I can get that working how I need :) Yes databases of course would be ideal but I don't need something that big for this, this is just my first little python program :) i can write stats to the file (and i have another file of champion names that i lookup to ensure something valid is being entered, it also supports abbreviations like tf, mf, kog), now it's just about displaying them and then i'll try to do some tracking and stuff. Thanks again I'll try to work this into what I have :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it too late to restructure your data?

```
>>> Caitlyn = {'games': [{'date': (2012, 11, 24),
                      'gameid': '00006',
                      'outcome': 'Win',
                      'stats': {'assists': 6, 'deaths': 4, 'kills': 13}}]}
>>> game02 = {'date': (2012, 11, 24),
              'gameid': '00007',
              'outcome': 'Loss',
              'stats': {'assists': 4, 'deaths': 3, 'kills': 16}}
>>> Caitlyn['games'].append(game02)
```

You use a list of dictionaries for each player, and save them into their own object, it pickles nicely, or it could be used as is in a [document-based no-sql database](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html). Although this does remove a lot of the work you've done so far, the payoff is nice. Persistent storage, no parsing/writing to text, and the ability to use database-style logic to do the sort of searching you're talking about. Aggregate stats are another good bonus that comes to mind. Although this doesn't answer your question *right now*, I hope you at least consider this as an option.

Comment: I could do that but i'm new to python and part of what i'm trying to learn here is some text parsing and formatting so i really wanted to keep it in a sortof formatted nice thing and then rip the data out of that

Comment: I read your comment under the accepted answer...the databases we both suggested are document based, and are really, really fast to set up and easy to use. Definitely keep sqlite3 or mongodb in mind when expanding this idea. Also, if you do decide to make this script more like a program, try using a VCS (git is my favorite) and start learning those skills as well.